# Different behavior when selecting quote blocks vs. selecting parentheses blocks

Tags: cut-copy-paste, cursor-motions, normal-mode

When I have a line of code such as:

`result = function(myVar);`

then I can delete the text "myVar" with the command **di(** only if my cursor is already positioned inside the parentheses. However, when I'm working with this text:

`result = "myString";`

then I can delete the text "myString" with the command **di"** whether or not my cursor is already placed in the parentheses. Is there some reason for this? Thanks!

Edit: The linked duplicate answers the question, that parentheses can be nested, unlike quotations, and this means that there is no simple default behavior choice like there is with quotes. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Theres definitely an answer to this here or on SO... now to remember how I found it.

Comment: The duplicate is definitely on this site. I remember having one of my questions closed as a duplicate :)